# GTK Theme Foreground color not working

Tags: gtk, theme, gtk3

I am using a GTK3 theme called Numix. It looks very nice, but the foreground color in dialogs is almost exactly the same as the background color.
I have tried editing various lines in the theme file, but I cant change the foreground color to black.

[image: "Copying file...." is far too light]

Comment: You were right, I had the wrong version

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I just made a dumb fault, Kali uses GTK+ 3.4, and the theme didn't support that. Luckily I found a version of the theme for 3.4 [here](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/147584913/numix-gtk-theme_1.9%7Eprecise.tar.gz)